# How do I debug Java code inside a "try {...}" block?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I (Java newbie) am running a Java program in Eclipse (project I downloaded from SourceForge). When I debug it, it always ends up at this location, which occurs after a 50-line try block:

```
catch (Exception ex){
    System.err.println("PROCESSING ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
    helpFormatter.printHelp(usage, options);
}
```

How can I find and debug the line of code that triggers this exception? (i.e. see the line number, inspect local variables, evaluate expressions, etc.) If I place a breakpoint after the catch, I don't see any way to get back to the original error or at least find out the line number. I could step through the code in the try block, but there are a lot of loops, so that could get extremely time consuming.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Print the stack trace. `ex.printStackTrace();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the stacktrace. You can find inyside an Eclipse tab somewhere, or print it directly when you catch the exception:

```
catch (Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Inspecting the stacktrace is the fast and most secure way to find your error quickly. Even if you set a breakpoint (or worst use some print to locate the last statement executed) you won't be able to determine exactly where the exception occurred.
In fact the exception could have been raised a lot deeper inside your calls stack, not necessarily in the first method called after the breakpoint.

Comment: You can use Exception Breakpoints to stop whenever an Exception is thrown. It'll pause the execution at the point where the exception was specifically thrown. See my answer below. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Add an "Exception Breakpoint". It'll stop at the root cause of the Exception where the problem first appears.

First determine what type of specific exception is being thrown - do this by setting a breakpoint within the catch block, and see what sort of exception ex is (by looking at it in the variables window). Remove the breakpoint, and hit F8 to continue on.

Now add an Exception Breakpoint. This is done by going to the Breakpoint view, and clicking on the icon that looks like "J!". Specify the specific type that you saw for ex. Now run the code, and it should stop at the point where the exception is thrown.

On another note: It's generally not a good idea to simply catch exception, you're better off trying to catch the specific types, though like you said, it's not your code.

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the try block and in the debug view you will be able to see all the details you're interesed in: the line number, inspect local variables, evaluate expressions, etc

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint in the first line of the try-block and step to the next line until it jumps to the catch block. Then you know you got the exception on that line. Then you can examine the exception to see what went wrong. Since you can't "go back" you probably will debug again to see what caused the problem.

But for most cases it's enough you look at the line indicated in the stack trace. You can put the breakpoint in this line, if you want to examine the state.

Comment: Even easier than having to go line-by-line, is to simply add an Exception Breakpoint. It'll stop at the line that is throwing the Exception. See my answer below. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily remove the try/catch block, so that the debugger will stop on the exception. (You might have to cheat and add `throws Exception` to your method signatures.)

Answer (score -1):

The best debugging solution for me is to place multiple Print statements after each major block of code.

```
System.out.println("1");

//Code1 block

System.out.println("2");

//code 2 block

System.out.println("3");

//code 3 block

System.out.println("4");
```

By doing this, you can see which is the last print statement that executes and modify it. the last number that prints and then the catch statement's stack trace should help.